# Cross-Site Search in Sharepoint 2013 Foundation

Tags: 2013, development, search, search-scope, fast-search

My question is simple. How can I configure Sharepoint 2013 Foundation to have cross-site searches. For example: I have 4 sites in all. Marketing, Advertising, Human Resources and Office. If I am in the Marketing Department site but want to search all four sites for a file, how can I configure Sharepoint to do that.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by cross site?

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in Foundation, I spend most of my day in Standard and Enterprise, but my understanding of Foundation search limitations is that you can only search a within a Site Collection and not across them with Foundation Search.